# Java 8 Time API: Comparing YearMonth to LocalDate?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Is there a convenience method to compare a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) against a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (or any other temporal) within Java 8 time API?

I wonder as so many methods support TemporalAccessors, whether I just looked at the wrong place and that there indeed exist such a convenience method. Any hints are highly appreciated.

To make the question clearer: if I compare `YearMonth` to `LocalDate` I am only interested in the comparison of `month` and `year` (the common denominator of both).

Answer (score 2):

YearMonth and LocalDate are not directly comparable just because LocalDate holds members for days that are not defined in the yearMont class.

you can write your own

```
private boolean checkTemporal(YearMonth yM, LocalDate lD) {

    return yM.getMonthValue() == lD.getMonthValue() && yM.getYear() == lD.getYear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping one temporal into the common denominator type that is required for comparison seems to be rather convenient, e.g. for comparing a `YearMonth` with a `LocalDate` the `LocalDate` is first transformed to a `YearMonth`:

```
LocalDate someDate = ...
YearMonth someMonth = ...

YearMonth.from(someDate).equals(someMonth)

// or compareTo if required
```

Thinking more about it, it probably makes sense that there isn't a universal `compare`-method as the comparison stays specific. There is no guarantee that someone just wants to compare the common denominator of both.

Comment: and Why have you added this explanation as an Answer? you should add this in your question's explanation.

Comment: because it _is_ an answer to the question.

Comment: @NeerajJain, it happens that someone answers their own question within minutes after asking, I don’t know why, but it is generally considered OK to do.

Comment: When you search for something and don't find any solution, someone else might search for the same. Now I think the question was probably not so well-written, but the answer is valid nonetheless.

Comment: @OleV.V. **I added my current approach as an answer** This line was mentioned initially by OP, so OP already had the answer/approach before even posting the question....So It's better to mention the same in question's explanation rather than posting an approach as an answer

Comment: @NeerajJain note that this solution as with any other question's answer, is just a proposal how it could be solved. If you have another approach, please do state it. If you have another suggestion, please go ahead. I am more than happy to improve anything. I just don't think that we gain much, if you continue to cite, what I wrote at the beginning, which, I already said, was a mistake to mention anyway.